# split() doesn't works properly

Tags: java, android, regex, split

I have a list of "serialized" object, objects are separated by `$$` and object attributes are separated by `$`

I have to split it in [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) to retrieve object values...

For instance:

> zfzzfzfTitre$Interpretessfcqfqfz$Genresqqqcqvqv$URLqdqddqdqdqd$0$$zfzzfzfTitresss$Interpretessfcqfqfzscsc$Genresqqqcqvqvcs$URLqdqddqdqdqd$1$$zfzzfzfTitresss$Interpretessfcqfqfzscsc$Genresqqqcqvqvcs$URLqdqddqdqdqd$2$$zfzzfzfTitresss$Interpretessfcqfqfzscsc$Genresqqqcqvqvcs$URLqdqddqdqdqd$3$$

But when I split to have the objects into an array with `listTemp.split("\\$$")`

the array size is 1

Could you help me please?

The code works on [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu)

Comment: Problem solved in adding \\ before each regex char

Comment: because there are many $ you need to specify the index of particular $ sign from where you want to split.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape all `$` signs

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UVfbwo/1)**

```
listTemp.split("\\$\\$");
```

Otherwise it'll parse the second `$` as and `end-of-line` anchor

Comment: I think for the case of Java it needs to be \\$\\$, not just `\$\$.